# Classifying data into 3 classes with a binary classifier model

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, text-classification

Hi I am new to Machine Learning. I have a task of classifying data into 3 classes. I have data for only 2 classes. I have used SVM Linear Classifier for the classes for which I have data (2 classes say A and B). Now there is another third class C for which I don't have any data. is there a way that I can use this binary classifier and predict if a sample doesn't belong to any of the 2 classes(A and B) then it must belong to C ?

Comment: did you try anything? any code?

Comment: and how would the algo be able to decide if it's none of the only two class of the above? the only way to to do so is to set manual Thresholds and if those are not reach then put them into class C. Give us the code of your SVC please so i can modify it and help you.

Comment: @Radan as I mentioned I have classified A and B using SVM linear classifier. So I have code for that as a usual Binary classifier.

Comment: @Alexis svm = SVC(kernel='linear') svm.fit(X, y) X_train, X_test = X[:splitNum], X[splitNum:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:splitNum], y[splitNum:]

    y_pred = svm.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed eventually use your model by observing if a specific threshold (activation) is met or not but I am not sure what will be good in practice. I doubt you can find a stable threshold values that will successfully divide the dimension so you can classify class C.
I would rather try another approach. I would concat A and B and train an outlier detector such as [One Class SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html). Then you would be able to classify C i.e it is neither A nor B .

Comment: how would you concatenate A and B classes ?

Comment: @ManasviniGanesh If you ask about code impl it depends on what language you are codding. In terms of idea is to merge A and B into single collection.

Comment: A and B are two a column in a csv. They are texts.

Comment: Another multiclass classification solution could be error-correcting output codes. Check out whitepaper by Dietrich.